# How to send input from one form to other form in Camunda?

Tags: camunda, bpmn

I am creating a form from my BPD. I want the user to first make his order by filling out the required input for a order. The problem comes when I want to make a receipt. How do I send the input from one form (the input order form) to the other form (receipt form)?

I have tried to send the input with JavaScript but I don't really know JavaScript so I have no idea how I am supposed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, all field out form fields (or a model of all fields, for example json object) is stored as process variables when you complete the task.
You can then read the process variable with the input and use it to render the receipt from.
How this works in detail depends on the type of form you choose and if you are using camunda 7 or camunda 8.